# xamarin forms update UI with await/async

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, async-await

I am writting a very basic Xamarin Forms Application, with Visual Studio for Mac.
This application should work with PCL on Android and iOS.

I have an empty TableView on XAML file. What i want to do is to populate this TableView with data i will fetch from a webservice.

Here is my C# code:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

public async Task<List<MyItem>> LoadData()
{
    try
    {
        var response = await client.GetAsync(new Uri("http://example.com/myservice.php"));
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<MyItem>>(content);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return null;
    }

    return null;
}

async void Handle_Clicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    activity_indicator.IsRunning = true;
    var data = await LoadData();
    activity_indicator.IsRunning = false;

    mylistview.Root.Clear();
    foreach (var item in data)
    {
        TableSection section = new TableSection() { Title = item.GroupTitle };
        foreach (var subitem in item.subitems)
        {
            var cell = new TextCell() { Text = subitem.Title };
            cell.Tapped += on_item_tapped;
            section.Add(cell);
        }
        mylistview.Root.Add(section);
    }
}
```

I am new to await and async programming. I used to develop native iOS application with iOS delegates. I have heard that a thread cannot update UI: Can i made some UI updates in LoadData() method for example ?
So i am wondering if my code is good.
It looks fine because it works, but i want to know if this is a good thing to work like this ?

Comment: Using `async/await` here is the correct choice. `await` on the UI thread will capture the current context and resume on that context when the asynchronous call completes which makes updating the ui after the call finishes trivial as you can see. One suggestions I'd make is to factor out the code in `Handle_Clicked` into an item template but that has nothing to do with `async`.

Comment: Do you think the UI is reactive when the main thread is waiting on an await instruction ?

Comment: @Bob5421 Run the code and see for yourself.

Comment: I have tried in simulator only and it seems to be reactive

Comment: @Bob5421 Then there you go.

Answer (score 5):

I believe its

```
Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
{

});
```

Answer (score -3):

```
private void UpdateUI(Action action)
{
     this.Invoke(new Action(action), null);
 }
```

Usage: UpdateUI(()=> lable1.Text="Updated");

Comment: This code is not valid in Xamarin Forms, perhaps you were thinking WinForms and IsInvokeRequired?

Comment: Do you mean if i update UI controls inside async method, i need to work with this Invoke call ?

Comment: @Bob5421 No, you don't.

Comment: @JSteward If this *were* a winforms application, there's no reason to use `InvokeRequired`, although this isn't a winforms app, so it's moot.