# How do I update UI elements From within a Static Thread on Xamarin Forums Android

Tags: c#, multithreading, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am new to Xamarin Forms and wanted to update an UI element within a static Thread. This is my code:

```
Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Flightupdate));

static void Flightupdate()
{
    Box.Text = "Hi"; //This is a UI element that isn't avalible in this thread
}
```

Comment: Did you check the docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/Xamarin.Forms.Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread?view=xamarin-forms ?

Comment: There are numerous SO answers for this. One to get you started: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44638957/8395242

Comment: No, OP's problem is that `Box` is not referenceable from a static method.

Comment: Why did you make `Flightupdate` **static**? Remove `static` from that definition. If that causes a problem, because the calling function is `static`, then remove `static` from that as well. Keep going until it builds. If it builds, you are done - problem solved. OTOH, if you reach a function that won't compile if you remove its `static`, then add to question the function that won't build without static. And explain where that function is called from.